# My script is not either being called or working

Tags: javascript, html, object

I want someone to enter a code, and for the script to change the `<p id="output">` to the letter that corresponds with the code

```js
function decode() {
  var y = document.getElementById("code").value;
  if (y == "GE56D7B") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "a";
  }
  if (y == "L9OSD4W") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "b";
  }
  if (y == "HDD218F") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "c";
  }
  if (y == "LO9P14A") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "d";
  }
  if (y == "YY6CZX3") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "e";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Enter code here">
<button onclick="decode()">Enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working just fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: @David when I run it, nothing appears in “output” the background is black, but all the other text is white, since I made the body{ color: #fffff; } in <style>

Comment: Well, the code you're showing us on this page is literally working as designed on this page.  Click on "Run code snippet" in your question to see it.  Without any demonstrable problem there isn't much we can do.

Comment: If the problem is with styling, add the CSS to your snippet.

Comment: Are you typing the code with uppercase letters into the input?

Comment: @Barmar yes. For some reason the output was black, but it’s fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working perfectly:

```js
function decode() {
  var y = document.getElementById("code").value;
  if (y == "GE56D7B") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "a";
  }
  else if (y == "L9OSD4W") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "b";
  }
  else if (y == "HDD218F") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "c";
  }
  else if (y == "LO9P14A") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "d";
  }
  else if (y == "YY6CZX3") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "e";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Enter code here">
<button onclick="decode()">Enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

To make this code simpler and more concise, however, use an object:

```js
function decode() {
  var y = document.getElementById("code").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = codes[y];
}

var codes = {
  GE56D7B: "a",
  L9OSD4W: "b",
  HDD218F: "c",
  LO9P14A: "d",
  YY6CZX3: "e"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="code" placeholder="Enter code here">
<button onclick="decode()">Enter</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using and what version? `innerText` is usually more widely supported than `innerHTML` and since you’re not actually manipulating any HTML just operating with plaintext I’d say stick with `innerText`.

Check out [this post](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/innertext-vs-innerhtml) for more information.